# JavaScript Iterate event handlers/listeners

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Is there any way to iterate through all of a node's event handlers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.  Not unless you write a wrapper function that first adds the handler to an array and then adds it to the element.

Comment: I was afraid of that. I noticed that the w3c DOM3 has a eventListenerList but I don't think any browser has implemented it.

Comment: Yeah.  That'll be nice.  Some JS libraries (ASP.Net AJAX for sure) have a way to track these events, but in the past,I have always done it manually.